# Showing a service notification message box with an owner window is not a valid operation. Use the Show method that does not take an owner

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to keep the MessageBox on the top with the help of a new form.

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, message, heading, buttonType, icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, Options);
```

When I call this from a Form it works fine, but when I call the same method using a child popup Form (child of Parent usercontrol) then it throws the below Exception.

```
Exception: Showing a service notification message box with an owner window is not a valid operation. Use the Show method that does not take an owner.
```

The problem is with the option parameter where I tried to pass below options but both didn't work.

```
MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly
MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification
```

child (popProductionConfirmation) method call:

```
private void callMyMethod()
{
    ShowMessageInMessageBox("Automatic Posting Done", "Production Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
}

private void ShowMessageInMessageBox(string message, string heading, MessageBoxButtons buttonType, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxOptions Options)
    {
        CommonMethods.ShowMessageInMessageBox(message, heading, buttonType, icon, Options, this);
    }
```

The class CommonMethods with MessageBox:

```
public static void ShowMessageInMessageBox(string message, string heading, MessageBoxButtons buttonType, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxOptions Options, IWin32Window owner = null)
    {
        if (owner == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, message, "BTS: " + heading, buttonType, icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, Options);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(owner, message, "BTS: " + heading, buttonType, icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, Options);
        }
    }
```

Parent with child popup creation:

```
popProductionConfirmation objpopProductionConfirmation;
objpopProductionConfirmation = new popProductionConfirmation();
objpopProductionConfirmation.ShowDialog();
```

So, is there any way to keep the MessageBox on top or any way to validate this condition, or to resolve it?

Comment: I think you could use a NamedPipe to propagate the message to a desktop app that is used for inter-process communication, and the desktop app shows the message. The point of a service is that it runs regardless if there is an active desktop.

Comment: Where is the code that **actually** calls the `ShowMessageInMessageBox` child method? As presented, it's clear there is some key code missing here.

Comment: @JuanR updated the question, kindly check. Also is there any way to keep the MessageBox TopMost?

Comment: @Thrainder - what did you finally do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you all you need to know, particularly this part:

> Use the Show method that does not take an owner.

Looking at the Framework's source code:

```
if (owner != IntPtr.Zero && (options & (MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification | MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly)) != 0)
{ 
    throw new ArgumentException (SR.Get(SRID.CantShowMBServiceWithOwner)); 
}
```

It's specifically looking for a condition where you provide an owner and use either of the flags you are trying to use and it throws an error:

`SRID.CantShowMBServiceWithOwner` is defined as:

> Showing a service notification message box with an owner window is not
> a valid operation. Use the Show method that does not take an owner.

Which is the error you are seeing.

So either:

- Use a `Show()` overload that does **not** take an owner as a parameter, or
- Use one with owner as parameter that does **not** use the `MessageBoxOptions` parameter.

To keep the message box on top:

- If using owner, set the owner's TopMost property to `true`.
- If using the overload without owner, use the `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly` option.